# Django: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

My website has a system of alerts. When a certain action occurs the system loggs an alert in the following model:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    read = models.BooleanField #if this is a new alert of not
    for_user = models.ForeignKey(User) #which user will see it
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Many functions need to check the number of alerts a user has (Mostly to display the number of new alerts next to the alerts tab of the site). Because of that, I created this function:

```
@login_required()
def get_alertnum(user):
    alert_objects = Alert.objects.filter(read = False, for_user=user)
    num = 0
    for n in alert_objects:
        num += 1
    return num
```

Which is accessed by this function:

```
@login_required()
def posting_draft(request):
    user = request.user
    user_drafts = Draft.objects.filter(user = user)
    drafts = dict()
    for d in user_drafts:
        drafts[d.title] = d.id
    alertnum = get_alertnum(user)
    return render_to_response('posting_draft.html', {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, 'draft_l' : drafts, 'selected':"dr", alertnum: alertnum})
```

But I get the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/posting/drafts

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Knights',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/views.py" in posting_draft
  245.     alertnum = get_alertnum(user)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  19.             if test_func(request.user):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  185.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /posting/drafts
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: `@login_reqiured()` should be `@login_required`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to remove @login_required() decorator from the get_alertnum() function. The decorator  assumes the first argument is a request object and is trying to access the user attribute.

Also you could simplify and speed up the function by:

```
def get_alertnum(user):
    return Alert.objects.filter(read=False, for_user=user).count()
```

Below is an explanation of the count method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count

Comment: Good answer. The other option would be to pass it as `get_alertnum(request, user)`. But you are right, if `get_alertnum` is not a view, it does not need a view decorator.

Comment: No need to add the request argument when the function is not using it.

Comment: What I meant is if the OP wanted to keep the decorator, then you would need to pass the request object as the first arg. The decorator will consume it to check the login, and pass along the user to the function

Comment: Yes. But that would only make sense if it was a view and returning a response object on success. You don't want the function return a number normally and a HttpResponseRedirect on failure.

Answer (score 12):

This error also pops up when you use `@login_required` decorator on class. For class decoration use `@method_decorator(login_required)`. See more in the [Class based views docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Comment: Disagree, this is not necessarily the right answer to *this* question. The correct answer is accepted: OP does not work with classes in his code above.

Answer (score 2):

The `@login_required` decorator only works on functions whose first argument is a request.  Your stack trace is because it tries to use the `user` object as if it were a `request` object, and it doesn't work.  *(as the other answer points out, `user` objects don't have a `.user` attribute)*

Perhaps instead `get_alertnum()` could check `user.is_authenticated()` first, and  return `0` if the user is not authenticated.

For example:

```
def get_alertnum(user):
    if not user.is_authenticated():
        return 0
    else:
        return Alerts.objects.filter(read=False, for_user=user).count()
```